# CFFILE Upload all Issues - Coldfusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to use this code for uploading files to my server but is giving me an error.

This is the code:

```
 <cfif isdefined("form.submit")> 
   <cffile action="uploadall" destination="#expandpath('../../images/Uploads/after')#"> 
 </cfif> 
 <cfform action="#cgi.script_name#" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
   <cfinput type="file" name="attachment1"><br> 
   <cfinput type="file" name="attachment2"><br> 
   <cfinput type="file" name="attachment3"><br> 
   <cfinput type="submit" name=" submit" value="submit"> 
 </cfform>
```

This is the Error:

> The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
>
> Error Occurred While Processing Request
>
> Invalid content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
>
> The files upload action requires forms to use enctype="multipart/form-data".
>
> The error occurred in E:\sites\Example.Com\testing\handlers\upload\after.cfm: line 20

Comment: Are you running CF9 or 9.0.1? There were a number of issues with the file upload control in the original version of CF9 that were fixed in the 9.0.1 updater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you've moved on to a different solution, but I wanted to answer your question because the answer is plain crazy (and is stereotypical of some of the bizarre gotchas in Coldfusion). The problem is that [`<cfform>` simply doesn't support the enctype attribute](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fb7.html). If you want to upload files, you have to use a plain `<form>`. Weird, right?

(I suppose you could change the XSLT so that a cfform with a file input results in the enctype being set correctly automatically. But why it doesn't do this out of the box is beyond me.)

Comment: I am going to test that! Is the last thing that I would think because I would assume that if cfform doesn't support enctype then plain form wouldn't either. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it is supported. Extra html attributes are just passed straight through into the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Does the directory structure that you are referencing in the destination attribute exist '"#expandpath('../../images/Uploads/after')#"'?

If the destination attribute is not an absolute path then it is relative to ColdFusion's temp directory.  Not relative to your web root or the template that is running.

Here is the description from the docs [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7388.html)

Pathname of directory in which to upload the file. If not an absolute path (starting with a drive letter and a colon, or a forward or backward slash), it is relative to the ColdFusion temporary directory, which is returned by the GetTempDirectory function.

Comment: The path is correct. It was the first thing to check before I posted my question

Comment: Another issue could be that ColdFusion does not have rights to that directory.  Have you tried changing the destination to the temp directory itself #expandpath('./uploads')# to see if the issue persists?

Comment: Did you create the uploads folder in your ColdFusion temp directory?  I'm not sure that it will do that for you.

Comment: I decided to go with a different method to upload my files. Thanks for the help